# What do i get when i have a dataframe called "df" and i put df['column_name'][-1] in python?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, indexing

I have a dataframe called "df" with two columns which have  stock prices of small and big companies, from 1926-07 to 2018-12, monthly. When  i put  df['Low Cap'][0] i get the stock price of 1970-01 of small companies.. when i put df['Low Cap'][-1], i get the stock price of 1969-12 of small companies. My question is ¿Why i am geting the price of that year? it's not even in the middle. What is doing python when i put the bracket [-1] or [0] to the df[Low cap]??

picture

Thanks you very much

Comment: Selecting an element at that location from the `Series` by index value. Relative lookup is not supported by Series like that (at least in 1.3.0) so it would have something to do with the index values.

Comment: But the strange thing is that im not getting the last entry. In this case, the last entry its 2018-12. However, im geting the stock price of 1969-12 when i put df['Low Cap'][-1].

Comment: Right again, it would have to do with index value. Relative lookup is not supported by Series. Only by index value.

Comment: In this case, index value has the format date.time (1926-07, 1926-08... 2018-12). is that important?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you treat the column (series) as a list, then you can use the list indexing that you want.  See this toy example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Low Cap':['A', 'B', 'C', 'D']})

w = df['Low Cap'][0]   # A
# x = df['Low Cap'][-1]  # key error: -1
y = df['Low Cap'].tolist()[0]    # A
z = df['Low Cap'].tolist()[-1]   # D
```

You may have a -1 in your df index.  See this similar toy example for why referring to the series with an index gives different behavior than if you convert to list and then use the list index.

```
df['new index'] = [-1, 2, 5, 12]
df = df.set_index('new index')

df['new index'] = pd.to_datetime(df['new index'])

w = df['Low Cap'][12]   # D
x = df['Low Cap'][-1]   # A
y = df['Low Cap'].tolist()[0]    # A
z = df['Low Cap'].tolist()[-1]   # D
```

The df index -1 is datetime 1969-12-31 23:59:59.999999999, look at the df:

```
                              Low Cap
new index                            
1969-12-31 23:59:59.999999999       A
1970-01-01 00:00:00.000000002       B
1970-01-01 00:00:00.000000005       C
1970-01-01 00:00:00.000000012       D
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I still dont understand, because when i put df['Low Cap'][-1], i dont get a error, i get the value of stock price on 1969-12. My index has the format date time, if it is important.

Comment: You are getting whatever -1 returns, without crashing, maybe because there is some index that is -1 in your data.  But as you see, -1 is not the last item -- because it's a series not a list.  If you want to use indexing as if the series were a list, convert it to a list.  I'll edit my answer to show another example.

Comment: Ok, but the strange thing is that i dont have any -1 in my index. In this case, index value has the format date.time (1926-07, 1926-08... 2018-12), and it start at1926-07  (July of 1927) and ends in 2018-12 (december of 2018). I dont know why, but when i put df['Low Cap'][0], the indexing start in 1970-01.. then, if i put df['Low Cap'][1], i get the vlue of the row that has the index 1970-02

Comment: The value -1 is a valid value for datetime, it is 1969-12-31 23:59:59.999999999.  I edited the answer again to show an example.

Comment: Aaaah, and always in every data, if i have  date.time index, the 1970-01-01 will be always the index = 0???

Comment: Exactly, you can use the toy example I provided to check all the values, e.g., 0 = 1970-01-01 00:00:00.000000000.  Can you accept my answer?

Comment: Aaah nice! Thanks you very much! Of course, answered accept!